# jquery background positioning of background sprite

Tags: jquery, html, css

On load - am running the following as an animation, CSS background position of a sprite and the appearance of a text block.  All is working sans the css.background. Anyone know why jquery appears to be ignoring the css call?  Or a suggested work around?

```
function roll_a() {
$("#a").css("background-position", "0px -444px");
$("#a_text").delay(1000).slideDown();
$("#a").css("background-position", "0px 0px");
$("#a_text").delay(500).slideUp();

$("#b").css("background-position", "0px -216px");
$("#b_text").delay(2000).slideDown();
$("#b").css("background-position", "0px 0px");
$("#b_text").delay(500).slideUp();
}
```

This however this is working elsewhere, but just on mouseover.

```
    $("#a").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#a").css("background-position", "0px -444px");
    $("#a_text").slideDown();
    }).mouseleave(function() {
    $("#a").css("background-position", "0px 0px");
    $("#a_text").slideUp();
    });
```

Comment: Are you able to post a full example on fiddle mate ? If you use some background position, you should have a background image somewhere, can you also show that ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct syntax in jQuery is:

```
$("#a").css("backgroundPosition", "0px -444px");
```

***backgroundPosition*** instead of ***background-position***

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED.

JQuery was so fast ....  That it moved the background positions in an instant - not even a blink.  By using setTimeout was able to slow it down enough for the effect to show.

```
$("#a_text").delay(1000).slideDown();
   setTimeout( function(){
   $("#a").css("background-position", "0px -444px");
},1000);

$("#a_text").delay(500).slideUp();
   setTimeout( function(){
   $("#a").css("background-position", "0px 0px");
},2000);
```